# Error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql

I have a `select` query which calls the `TOTALFACTOR` function.. However, this simple function throws an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Query:

```
select wwid, TOTALFACTOR(days) 
from table A
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TOTALFACTOR] (@days int)      
RETURNS decimal(18,4)
AS              
BEGIN
    declare @total as decimal(18,4)

    if @days is NULL 
       return 0

    if (@days >= 0 and @days < 1461) 
        set @total = (@days * 0.01369863)  
    else if(@days >= 1462 and @days< 2557)
        set @total = (1461 * 0.01369863) + ((@days - 1461) * 0.018263014)
    else if(@days >= 2558 and @days< 3653)
        set @total = (1461 * 0.01369863) + ((2557 - 1462) * 0.018263014) + ((@days - 2557) * 0.01369863)

    return @total
```

Comment: it throws that error when passing what value for `days`?

Comment: Integer - DATEDIFF(d, H.Date,convert(date,getdate())) as days

Comment: are you use the days field from Table A is an integer data type?  Also in Java you get errors when comparing numbers like an int to null so you may want to check the @days is null comparison.

Comment: @raylee The days is an calculated field. Yes it has the NULL value. But isn't it i had catch the NULL from the function -  if days is NULL return 0

Comment: I have tried - select wwid, TOTALFACTOR(ISNULL(days,0)), but same error

Comment: What is the minimum `H.Date` in your table? Run `SELECT MIN(H.Date) AS MinDate FROM [whatever table] H`and post it as a comment, please.

Comment: My min date is 1984-10-26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `BIGINT`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TOTALFACTOR] (@days BigInt)      
RETURNS decimal(18,4)
AS              
BEGIN
    declare @total as decimal(18,4)

    if @days is NULL 
       return 0

    if (@days >= 0 and @days < 1461) 
        set @total = (@days * 0.01369863)  
    else if(@days >= 1462 and @days< 2557)
        set @total = (1461 * 0.01369863) + ((@days - 1461) * 0.018263014)
    else if(@days >= 2558 and @days< 3653)
        set @total = (1461 * 0.01369863) + ((2557 - 1462) * 0.018263014) + ((@days - 2557) * 0.01369863)

    return @total
END
```